# Symmetric key in the request body of the http request

Tags: encryption, jmeter, encryption-symmetric

I am getting the symkey followed by the encoded value in the one of the request body while recording a UI flow in jmeter.

Is there a way to decipher this as my request fails after sometime and I get public key in the response.

Answer (score 0):

For sure there is, take a look at [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Cipher](https://www.baeldung.com/java-cipher-class) class

You can access the full response from the JSR223 PostProcessor as `prev.getResponseDataAsString()` where `prev` stands for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) or a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) value as `vars.get('your-variable-name-here')` where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)

Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on above and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements

Comment: Thanks for this Dmitri, but looks like even I dicepher it I am not sure where it is getting generated. I could only found some js fun tion related to this